# How do I change this from Scanner to BufferedReader?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a code here that uses Scanner to get the next line and I'm now trying to convert it in where I can use File Reader and Buffered Reader.

```
@Override
    public List<Request> readFile() throws IOException, BarsException {

        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

        String digitFormat = "[0-9]+";
        String dateFormat = "^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])/[0-9]{4}$";
        int rowCounter = 0;

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

        //using Scanner instead of bufferedReader
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.getFile())){
            if(!scanner.hasNextLine())
                throw new BarsException(BarsException.NO_REQUESTS_TO_READ);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                rowCounter++;
                String lineContent = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] contentArray = lineContent.split(",");
                String billingCycle = contentArray[indexSetter.billing_Cycle.getValue()];
                String startDate = contentArray[indexSetter.start_Date.getValue()];
                String endDate = contentArray[indexSetter.end_Date.getValue()];

                if(startDate == null || !startDate.matches(dateFormat)){
                    throw new BarsException(BarsException.INVALID_START_DATE_FORMAT + rowCounter + ".");
                }

                if(endDate == null || !endDate.matches(dateFormat)){
                    throw new BarsException(BarsException.INVALID_END_DATE_FORMAT + rowCounter + ".");
                }

                if(billingCycle == null || !billingCycle.matches(digitFormat)){
                    throw new BarsException(BarsException.INVALID_BILLING_CYCLE + rowCounter + ".");
                }

                if(AbstractInputFile.MIN_BILLING_CYCLE > Integer.valueOf(billingCycle) || AbstractInputFile.MAX_BILLING_CYCLE < Integer.valueOf(billingCycle)){
                    throw new BarsException(BarsException.BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_ON_RANGE + rowCounter + ".");
                }

                Request request = new Request();
                request.setStartDate(LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter));
                request.setEndDate(LocalDate.parse(endDate, formatter));
                request.setBillingCycle(Integer.parseInt(billingCycle));

                requests.add(request);
            }
        }

        return requests;
    }
```

Do I have to recode everything again or do I only need to change these parts of my code:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.getFile())){
            if(!scanner.hasNextLine())
                throw new BarsException(BarsException.NO_REQUESTS_TO_READ);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                rowCounter++;
                String lineContent = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] contentArray = lineContent.split(",");
                String billingCycle = contentArray[indexSetter.billing_Cycle.getValue()];
                String startDate = contentArray[indexSetter.start_Date.getValue()];
                String endDate = contentArray[indexSetter.end_Date.getValue()];
```

I've been trying to experiment to change it into Buffered Reader unfortunately when I launch the Spring Boot Application and try it in Postman it resends me an Error 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Right now it says No file to write the output file

Comment: That isn't an error message I recognize.  Copy and paste the **complete** stacktrace please ... into the **Question**.